# Plotly: How to plot candlestick charts on a subplot?

Tags: python, plotly, subplot, candlestick-chart

I am trying to plot a subplot which contains 14 candlestick charts of cryptocurrency data. (
https://www.kaggle.com/c/g-research-crypto-forecasting)

However, it seems that it can't display the figure properly.

Here is my code:

```
from plotly import subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = subplots.make_subplots(rows=7,cols=2)

for ix,coin_name in enumerate(asset_details["Asset_Name"]):
   coin_df = crypto_df[crypto_df["Asset_ID"]==asset_names_dict[coin_name]].set_index("timestamp")
   coin_df_mini = coin_df.iloc[-100:]
   column = lambda ix: 1 if ix % 2 == 0 else 2
   candlestick = go.Candlestick(x=coin_df_mini.index, open=coin_df_mini['Open'], high=coin_df_mini['High'], low=coin_df_mini['Low'], close=coin_df_mini['Close'])
   fig = fig.add_trace(candlestick, row=((ix//2) + 1), col=column(ix))
   fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)

fig.update_layout(title_text="Candlestick Charts", height=2800)
fig.show()
```

And here is the problem:

[rangeslider_problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKeaU.png)

No matter I plot the figure with or without the rangeslider, it's always out of shape.

Comment: Is there any way to keep the sliders in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hide the slider on the x-axis unit created in the subplot. My answer was to do all the subplots manually. I don't have time to deal with this right now, but there is also a way to update the output content in a loop process.

```
fig.update_layout(xaxis1=dict(rangeslider=dict(visible=False)),
                  xaxis2=dict(rangeslider=dict(visible=False)),
                  xaxis3=dict(rangeslider=dict(visible=False)),
                  xaxis4=dict(rangeslider=dict(visible=False)),
                  xaxis5=dict(rangeslider=dict(visible=False)),
                  xaxis6=dict(rangeslider=dict(visible=False)),
                  xaxis7=dict(rangeslider=dict(visible=False)),
                  xaxis8=dict(rangeslider=dict(visible=False)),
                  xaxis9=dict(rangeslider=dict(visible=False)),
                  xaxis10=dict(rangeslider=dict(visible=False)),
                  xaxis11=dict(rangeslider=dict(visible=False)),
                  xaxis12=dict(rangeslider=dict(visible=False)),
                  xaxis13=dict(rangeslider=dict(visible=False)),
                  xaxis14=dict(rangeslider=dict(visible=False)),
                 )
```

[image]

Comment: Please add the above code. If my answer is helpful to you, please click the check mark on my answer to accept it.

Comment: Thanks! It does work. And I figure out that I can use `fig.update_xaxes(rangeslider_visible=False)` in the loop.

Comment: What is the reason for your unacceptance of my response?